# jQuery Validate: Detecting underlying click instead of blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, bootbox

I have a form that I create within a Bootbox (itself a layer on top of Bootstrap's modal). Once it is created, I call

`$('#myForm').validate()`

on it.

The desirable part of the behaviour is that now as the user tabs through the forms, they can see immediate feedback that they've messed up one of the fields. Entered a non-email address before hitting "tab" or clicking elsewhere? Warning and error message. Great!

But the undesirable thing is that the blur eats other events. So, if a user instead chooses to hit "cancel" (knowing full well that the form is invalid), the click on the cancel is not heard and its handler will not fire. A second click (now that the focus is off the form altogether) and cancel fires as expected. I don't want the users to have to click twice.

I saw a technique for disabling the blur altogether, but then the desirable behaviour described above is then lost, which I do not want either. Ideally, a "well, I blurred, but I also know what the user was clicking" is what I'm after.

[EDIT TO ADD:]

It has come to my attention that this is confusing, so let me try a different approach to the question: is it possible to be working on a form (that has had `.validate()` called on it), then click on any other clickable item on the whole page and have its click handler successfully fire?

[EDIT AGAIN:]

Based on Sparky's demo, I wired up a warning to show below the inputs on blur. So, to see the problem in action, fire up this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bd1fhpu3/

Then click into one of the input fields BEFORE clicking "just a button". Click in an upper sliver of "just a button" to make sure that the warning labels have pushed it out of the cursor's hotspot on release of the mouse button.

Anyhow, this just explains what the problem is. Solving it is probably not within the scope of the question anymore, but it seemed worth sharing in case anybody else comes across this. To solve, I will either need to override Bootbox's click event to be a mousedown event instead of a click (then you don't need to press and release), or I can "Band-Aid"(tm) the solution by avoiding relocating the button. Maybe a static-height dialog that's tall enough to accomodate the form and any possible warnings. Definitely somewhat of a "hack" like this because you just never know if you're going to do other things later that make the problem appear again. But it'd be a quick and easy temp fix.

Comment: Very confusing.  Refer to [`onfocusout` in the docs](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#onfocusout) and write a custom function that does whatever you want.

Comment: How do you expect the programming to know what is inside the user's mind?  Whether user hits cancel or clicks on the next field, in both cases they are focusing out.

Comment: onfocusout will allow you to change what happens on focus, but you're in the event loop that has no idea about the click. You could maybe do something with your mouse's x/y coordinates. It's not about mind reading. The user has clicked, and they have clicked on top of a cancel button. There's no need to read minds, there's just the need to allow the click to propagate. I don't mind if the blur ALSO triggers; preventing that part would require mind-reading.

Comment: The moment they click on the cancel button, the focus out has **already happened**, which is the problem.  And `onfocusout` allows you to change what happens when focus is lost, not gained, and really has nothing to do with clicking.  If you want to write complex code that follows the mouse's x/y position in order to determine user's intent, then you might as well write validation code from scratch.

Comment: Answer to your amended question is "yes, `click` handler successfully fires".  See:  https://jsfiddle.net/L1x3bqug/  ~ Maybe it's time to see a more complete demo.

Comment: I agree, Sparky. If the answer to the amended question is "yes", I'm even more confused than ever. It will be beyond difficult to create a demo for you, but I accept that we're going to get nowhere further without it. I will see what I can do, and in the meantime, thanks for being a swell guy.

Comment: Well, for what it's worth, the mystery (such as it is) is solved although I still don't know how to fix yet. When the user clicks the "Cancel" button, the blur fires first, which is rendering out some error messaging. This causes a reflow and the cancel button is pushed down X pixels. Since a click is a mousedown and mouseup on the "same spot", and the button is moved, its click handler does not fire. Proved concept by pressing down on mouse button, seeing the blur handler fire, moving the cursor back to the button, and releasing. Works every time. Could artifically prevent the reflow for now.

Comment: Added an update above which includes a modified Sparky's demo to artifically reproduce the problem. I don't expect a magic solution, though... the problem is inherent to the way DOM and events work, and this was just unexpected.

Comment: Created a version of your fiddle that uses the dialog helper: https://jsfiddle.net/Ln6x7eja/1/. It seems to close regardless of whether the form is closed, so not sure exactly why your case doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: @TiesonT. Your version of the demo is failing in the same way. First you fire up the modal. Then you click into one of the required fields. Then you try to click "Cancel" (click in the upper section of the button to be sure). Sometimes you might "win" the race condition with a brief click, so to really emphasize what's going on, hold the mouse button down for a good second before releasing it. Thanks for taking the time to throw the demo into the modal, though!

Comment: @GregPettit I suppose that makes sense, although it's not something I think I can handle in Bootbox. Changing the event from a click to a mouse-down is a breaking change, which I'm really trying to avoid (should mention that I'm one of the active maintainers of Bootbox, in case you were wondering). It does sound like a fixed-height modal is your best option, or you can add a mouse-down handler and trigger a click on the same button (might get a bit sketchy in practice, though).

Comment: Hey Tieson, I very much agree with everything you said. We ultimately elected to leave it as it is for now, since we don't want to do any hacks. It's definitely not Bootbox's fault, or anybody's really. Just one of those unexpected UI quirks that we will either need to work around or accept as a known "issue" (for lack of a better word). Thanks again for chiming in!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for posterity, here's an "answer" such as it is. Maybe it will help somebody SOME day; you just never know.

There is no code that is operating "incorrectly" and therefore there is not really a fix nor code sample to provide. Here's what was happening:

1. User is in focus in field
2. User presses mouse button down (but the release action hasn't happened yet)
3. Blur event fires, which causes form error warnings to appear below the fields. This also had the net effect of pushing the "cancel" button down the Y axis of the screen
4. User releases the mouse button, which would normally complete the "click" handler.

HOWEVER, in #4, since the "cancel" button is no longer under the cursor, the click event listener bound to the button does not fire.

The demo, for as long as it lives on the internet, will be in a comment below. However, providing a code sample to go with it is pointless. When the demo dies, I will remove the comment.

---

Possible Steps (workarounds/hacks) that I elected NOT to pursue thus far:

1. Modify the dialog such that the button does not move when mousedown event fires, meaning the "click" event is completed successfully
2. Provide custom code that substitutes the mousedown event for the click event on the button. However, this causes a loss of fairly common UI convention
3. Force user to press ESC to cancel, rather than clicking a button
4. [credit to Tieson T. via comment] One possible option, if you can use some custom styles on the error messages, is to hide them with `visibility: none` rather than `display: non`e. The former would hide the text but still reserve the vertical space of the text, which the latter doesn't (hence why your modal is expanding). This would keep the button from possibly shifting during the focusout event. You would wind up with extra whitespace, but you could knock some of that off by removing the bottom margin on the form-group (assuming you're using it)

I'm sure there are other workarounds, but that's a starting point.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Ln6x7eja/1/ -- it's "safest" or "most reliable" to click in the upper part of the button and hold it for a brief moment before releasing.

Comment: One possible option, if you can use some custom styles on the error messages, is to hide them with `visibility: none` rather than `display: none`. The former would hide the text but still reserve the vertical space of the text, which the latter doesn't (hence why your modal is expanding). This would keep the button from possibly shifting during the focusout event. You _would_ wind up with extra whitespace, but you could knock some of that off by removing the bottom margin on the `form-group` (assuming you're using it) with `mb-0`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the built in `onfocuout` function since the JavaScript cannot possibly know the different between focusing out to another field and focusing out to the cancel button.

You'll have to completely disable `onfocusout` and write some custom event handlers.

Your code is sparse, so my answer will be very generic.

```
$('#myForm').validate({
    // other options here
    onfocusout: false;   // disable default blur event
});
```

Then write an event handler that programmatically triggers validation on the form when they focus to an `input`, and will do nothing when they focus over to anything, like a cancel button.

```
$('#myForm input').on('focus', function() {
    $('#myForm').valid();  // trigger validation on the form
});
```

However, this will trigger validation on the entire form.  If you only want to trigger validation on the one field losing focus, then you're back to square one, because the event only knows focus was lost, not where it's going.

Comment: The code is sparse because it is meaningless. You don't need to see the Bootbox dialog's code to know that it has a click event listener on a button. The validate code is exactly as written in the original question: no options. I appreciate you taking your time and sharing your expertise, though. I've added a clarification in the original question if it helps. What you suspected is correct, though: it's sub-optimal to validate the whole form at once.